# Why is heroku not detecting my python buildback?

Tags: python, git, heroku

Here is my repo: https://github.com/amanmibra/me3thx-reddit-bot/tree/deploy-branch

Everytime I try to deploy on the site or through the Heroku CLI, heroku is unable to detect my buildpack.

```
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 1.89 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Failed to detect app matching https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/php.tgz buildpack
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to me3thx-reddit-bot.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/me3thx-reddit-bot.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/me3thx-reddit-bot.git'
```

What am I doing wrong? I have only used Heroku for node.js projects, so, it is possible that I am missing something that may be necessary for python projects.

Comment: Everytime this happens to me, I just pass the `--force` parameter with the `git push` ---> `git push --force heroku master`

Comment: Just tried it. Didn't work.

Comment: What was your error message when you tried it?

Comment: The same as above

Comment: I'm sure you followed this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks but I'm just checking. Did you?

Comment: I've skimmed through it

Comment: Because your error talks about `https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/php.tgz` but you want to use a python buildpack

Comment: I'm quite sure skimming and implementing will help more.

Comment: I think it maybe the xml files that pycharm has added. I will check if removing those will fix the issue

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: Please go through the guide and set your buildpack to the one you want.